# How to change parts of CSS/HTML adding a single drop-down to a website

Tags: html, css

I have to edit some CSS to add a dropdown to a site. I didn't create this external CSS, I just have to edit it. I found [this w3schools.com page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp) but it uses inline CSS.

This is a repost because the original was closed before I could add what was needed.

It's for one element on one site, possibly inline CSS would work for this.

I would have to edit multiple HTML files as all pages have the same header menu. Once I got one finished and working correctly, it would be just a copy paste though.

Editing the HTML is somewhat easy but the CSS is a pain. I just am not sure what to do. Can someone please help? I won't be redoing the CSS either just editing it. I tried using the CSS and HTML information from the W3 Schools page but it just didn't show up properly. The Site I am trying to edit is besolutions.org. I didn't create it I'm just to edit it. And yes I know it is really old code. There are no plans to redo the whole site even though it needs it.

Below is the CSS and HTML I need to change. The drop-down would be in the top-nav section.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

body {
    font-size:100%;
    font-family: Arial,'Lucida Grande',Verdana,sans-serif;
    background:#111111 url(images/background.gif) repeat-x top left;
}

#container {
  width:1000px;
  background:#FFF;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#body_space {
  padding:0 8px 0 8px;
}
  
#header {
  width:984px;
  background:#FFF;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.cls {
clear:both;
}

/* logo and small tagline */

#logo-image {
    height: 133px;
    width: 136px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#111111 url(images/background.gif) repeat-x top left;
}

#logo-block {
  height:133px;
  width:auto;
  float:inherit;
  text-align:end;
  background:#111111 url(images/background.gif) repeat-x top left;
}

#logo {
    padding-top:44px;
    line-height:13px;
    font:60px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
/*  padding-left:27px;                             */
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#logoBlue {
  font:48px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
  align: left;
  color:#005795;
}

#tagline {
  font:14px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
  color:#5A5A5A;
  padding-left:97px;
}

/* end logo and small tagline */

/* top navigation and menu */

#top-nav-bg  {
  background:transparent url(images/topnavbar.gif) no-repeat top left;
  height:38px;
  width:984px;
}
    
#top-nav {
  height:38px;
  width:984px;  
}
  
#top-nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0px;
}
  
#top-nav ul li {
  background-image: url(images/topnavdivider.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 38px;
}

#top-nav ul li:last-child {
  background-image: none !important;
}
    
#top-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
}
    
#top-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #FDA041;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
 
#top-nav li {
     float:left;
}
    
/* end top navigation bar */

/* image of clouds with large header */

#clouds {
  background:url(images/clouds.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  width:984px;
  height:156px;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  margin-top:9px;
}

#clouds-tagline1 {
  font:24px Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
  padding:40px 0px 0px 40px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:justify;
  /*letter-spacing:-2px;*/
}
#clouds-tagline2 {
  font:48px Georgia, Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 367px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:left;
  letter-spacing:-2px;
}

/* end image of clouds with large header */


#page {
  width:1000px;
  min-height:206px;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  background:#FFF;
  padding-top:8px;
}

#page-padding {
  padding:3px 8px 0px 8px;
}

/* main page content */

#content {
  float:left;
  width:691px;
  background:#FFF url(images/page-background.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}

#content-full {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background:#FFF url(images/page-background-full.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}

#content-padding {
  padding:15px;
}

#content-full-padding {
  padding:15px;
}

#content h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    padding:5px 5px 10px 5px;
    color:#494949;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#content-full h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    padding:5px 5px 10px 5px;
    color:#494949;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#content p {
    padding:0px 5px 10px 5px;
    font:15px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
    text-align:left;
    color: #494949;
}

#content-full p {
    padding:0px 5px 10px 5px;
    font:15px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
    text-align:left;
    color: #494949;
}

#content a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color:#0B3E70;
}
    
#content a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 4px #FDA041;
}


.grey {
  color:#494949;
}

/* end main page content */

/* right menu, navigation, newsletter */

#right-nav {
    float:right;
    width:283px;
    height:auto;
}

.right-nav-back {
  background:#FFF url(images/right-menu-bg.gif) repeat-y top left;
  width:283px;
}

.right-nav-top {
  background:#FFF url(images/right-menu-top.gif) no-repeat top left;
  width:283px;
  height:36px;  
}
.right-nav-top p {
  color:#FFF;
  font:13px Arial, "Times New Roman", Times;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:13px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.right-nav-bottom {
  background:#FFF url(images/right-menu-bottom.gif) no-repeat top left;
  width:283px;
  height:12px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
  
#right-nav ul
{
  list-style:none;
  text-align:left;
  padding-top:10px;
}
  
#right-nav li a
{
  background-image: url(images/right-menu-div.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  display:block;
  padding:13px 0px 18px 15px;
  line-height:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#005795 Times, serif;
  font-size:15px;
}



  
#right-nav li a:hover
{
    color:#005795;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
  
.right-nav-divider {
  background: transparent url(images/menu-divider.gif) no-repeat top left;
  width:226px;
  height:1px;
  padding-bottom:33px;
}

.button {
  background:transparent url(images/button.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  border:none;
  width:131px;
  height:31px;
  color:#FFF;
  font:bold 13px Arial, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:5px;
}

/* end right menu, navigation, newsletter */
```

```
           </div>
           <div class="cls"></div>
           <div id="top-nav-bg">
                <div id="top-nav" class="top-menu">
                     <ul>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                     </ul>                    
                </div>
           </div>
           <div id="top-nav-bg">
                <div id="top-nav" class="bottom-menu">
                     <ul>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Text</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="file.html">Text</a>
                      <a href="https://www.website.com">webpage title</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>                              
                          <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="file.html">Text</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your html is partial as it starts with an ending `div` tag.  The snippet does not contain the html and so shows an empty window. When I add the HTML to the snippet the results are indecipherable.  Also your sample seems to be just a cut and paste of code that doesn't work, where are your efforts so we can offer advice? Please see [ask]

Comment: That's just the area in the HTML that the dropdown is going to go. That's only about 50% of the CSS. Because those are the only area's in question.
I inherited a rats nest. 
I can add the rest but it does get messy.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt: simplify

It's difficult to inherit someone else's work.  The CSS has a lot going on.  My advice:

1. Comment it all out
2. Add the CSS that gets the dropdown working.
3. Then start adding back the styling a piece at a time. If it breaks the dropdown, don't add it back.

The key parts:

1. Floating navbar items.  This makes displaying the absolutely positioned dropdowns easier to display without need of setting `top`/`left` css.
2. Hover: The css that converts the dropdown div from `display:none` to `display:block` on `:hover`

In the CSS below uncomment the border properties to see the boundaries of the dropdown and its items.

```css
.navbar>* {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  /* border: 1px dashed gray; */
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* border: 4px solid green; */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">Dropdown &#x25BC;
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```